# Jquery this returns empty object when calling from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a normal function which works and when i console log this it returns jQuery.fn.init [small.expand, context: small.expand

My function below:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'h3.shipping-name small.expand', function (e) {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    console.log(me);
    var next = me.parent().next().next();
    if (next.is(":hidden")) {
        me.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    } else {
        me.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
    next.slideToggle();
});
```

But if i want to get it from another function like this:

```
var smallExpand = jQuery('h3.shipping-name small.expand');

smallExpand.on("click", function () {
    expandDetails();
});

function expandDetails(e) {

    alert("oki2");
    var me = jQuery(this);
    console.log(me);
    var next = me.parent().next().next();
    console.log(next)
    if (next.is(":hidden")) {
        me.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    } else {
        me.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
    next.slideToggle();
}
```

But it returns only empy object like this: jQuery.fn.init {}
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Problem with your implementation is that `this` doesn't refers to current element it refers to `window`. You could do `smallExpand.on("click", expandDetails);` or `expandDetails.call(this);`

Comment: instead of `this` use `e` to get the element clicked

Comment: try using `call` `expandDetails.call(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is that `this` doesn't refers to current element it refers to `window` object thus the code doesn't work

You can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the `this` value

```
smallExpand.on("click", function (event) {
    expandDetails.call(this, event);
});
```

---

Or, You could just pass the function reference to attach event handler

```
smallExpand.on("click", expandDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable first out side your functions, then you can retrieve it for later.

```
var me;
```

Then

```
function first() {
    me = $(this);
}
```

Now you can use the variable in another function

```
function thisorthat() {
    $(‘.class’).val(me);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling expandDetails as a static method.

as mentioned by @Satpal, you should just do `smallExpand.on("click", expandDetails);`.

`this` exists in the `smallExpand.on("click", function() {});` scope, but once you call `expandDetails();` it gets lost.